# Accessing google maps imagery from local services

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I developed an application using google maps and was wondering if it is possible to access google maps imagery from the local service.

For example: I presume the service connects to maps.google.com by default. In China they have ditu.google.cn, Spain has maps.google.es and so on.

I am not asking about the map language. Which other post explained is determined by the browsers's locale settings. Are there local versions for http://www.google.com/jsapi, a setting in the map object or anything else I can use? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a region parameter to the `script` tag to serve specific tiles and bias application behavior dependent on the locale.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Localization

(Scroll down to see **Region Localization**)

Comment: Thank you, the link put me in the right direction. Forgot to mention I am using jQuery. So something like this did the work 
`
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"> 


google.load("maps", "3", {
other_params : "sensor=false" ,base_domain : "ditu.google.cn" });
`
source: [link](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/#GoogleLoad)